JQuery not working on ASP.NET content page
I have Visual Studio 2022. I initially created a simple ASP.NET web application to test some jQuery. That worked.
I've now got the same code in a working ASP.NET web application and the jQuery is not being executed. The only difference being the later app is using a master page.
This is the installed jQuery:

I dragged and dropped the jQuery file jquery-3.7.1.js to the HTML page:

The Script word has been underlined and the message for that is:

Validation (XHTMI 1.0 transitional): Element 'script' is missing required attribute 'type'.

I'm assuming this is the problem as my test app is not displaying the same underlined and works, however this is what it looks like on the test app when dragged and dropped:

Any ideas why I have this problem?

In the browser, open network tab and see if jquery is not returning 404 HttpStatus. You may need to rework on relative path then.

"Element 'script' is missing required attribute 'type'." - (1) This isn't an error, just a warning (or even lower).  (2) What stops you from adding a type attribute, exactly as is done on the very next line of code?

XHTML has been dead for quite a while now, is there a reason you're still using it in 2024?

Need to see more markup- is this markup in the master page, or a child page of master? If child page,  then of course the script ref to jquery goes in master page, and wouldn't be required in the child page

@Albert D. Kallal. Sorry, I should have said its in the child page. I have also tried on the masterpage but with the same result.

@Shaan. I had a look at the Browser Network tab and jquery-3.7.1.js status was 200. I've tried several paths but still displays the same.

ok, then see my post below - you can't place nor have script references outside of the content templates for a child page.

Ok, so we are using a child page of a master page. In near all such cases then, the master page should have the script references.
However, you "can" place such script references in the child page. Just keep in mind that in the child page, it (eventually) winds up being rendered inside of the master page, and thus placement of the script references can VERY much matter.
Depending on your master template, when you create a child page, then you often find 2 sections of content. One part is (often, not always) rendered in the heading part of the page, and then the second content area is rendered inside of the master page "form" tag.
hence, starting a blank page, you tend to see this:
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" 
    AutoEventWireup="false" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
    CodeBehind="GridTest.aspx.vb" 
    Inherits="MyCalendar2.GridTest1" %>



<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">



</asp:Content>

Now, in above, I only have one content area. However, as I pointed out, that means you need to place ANY script refernece INSIDE of the content area.
Hence, this will NOT work:
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" 
    AutoEventWireup="false" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
    CodeBehind="GridTest.aspx.vb" 
    Inherits="MyCalendar2.GridTest1" %>


    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


</asp:Content>

And the editor will show this like this:

Note how the squiggles show, and hovering over the script tag we see this:

So in fact the error message is rather clear, and you can't place much of anything outside the content areas.
Hence, this then will work:
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

    your page markup goes here......

</asp:Content>

Of course, as I pointed out, you as a general rule want to place such script references in the master page, and thus you not need to have/use/place any such script references in each child page over and over. However, in some cases, I will place the script reference for the specific page (child or non child page), since it does not make sense to place such script references in all pages that don't need such a script reference.
However, some caution here is required, since where is the child page being placed? Is it in the root of the application, or say some nested folder? So, in above, seeing the "../" means I must have been nested in some folder (Grids\GridTest.aspx).
So, if you placing the script reference in the master page, then what happens if the child page is nested say a few folders deep?
Well, then I place the script reference in the master page, but use this expression:
<body>

    <form id="formm" runat="server">


        <%: Styles.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.css") %>
        <%: Styles.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.toast.min.css") %>
        <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/RadioNav.css?v=1.2") %>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">

            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" runat="server"  />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/bootstrap34.min.js" runat="server" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.13.2.min.js" runat="server"  />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.toast.min.js" runat="server" />                
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

Note again how the master page has the form tag, and your "content" page in your child page will thus render inside of the master page form tag. This of course means that the child pages can't use nor don't need nor allow any form tags in such pages. And note how due to having "runat=server", then we are allowed to use the "~/" that means root of the site. This type of addressing does NOT work for a script reference without a runat=server, and hence you have (are) using "../" to go down one folder. I suggest using the above "~/", but such addressing (from root) can only work with server side code.
I suppose the short version of above is that script tags in a child page can't be placed (nor should they) outside of the content template for such child pages. And since the child page can be nested deep in folders, then don't use "../" in the master page, since that nesting of the child page ALSO loads the master page at that "folder level". This in effect means that your master page script references REALLY need to use the "~/" with runat="server", since you really don't know where the child page is going to be located, and hard coded script references in master page will thus break all the time.
